# Background Image for UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am trying to  set  the background image for UINavigationBar.

I tried 2  types of methods,

```
 1. [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"KnavigationBarImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It is supported in ios 5, but crashes when run it in ios 4.3.

```
 2. self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"KnavigationBarImage.png"].CGImage;
```

It is working fine in ios 4 , But the image is not displaying in ios 5 Simulator.

I need the code which should work in both version 4 and 5.

Please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a method like this to find which OS the device has.

```
static int sIsiOS5 = -1;
+(BOOL)isIOS5
{
    if( -1 == sIsiOS5)
    {
        sIsiOS5 = 0;
        if( [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(brightness)])
        {
            sIsiOS5 = 1;
        }
    }
    return sIsiOS5;
}
```

While setting the image, check as following and then set the image.

```
if ( [Utilities isIOS5] ) {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"KnavigationBarImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
else
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"KnavigationBarImage.png"].CGImage;
}
```

Comment: I'd rather check whether the navigationBar responds to selector `setBackgroundImage:`

Comment: @ThomasMüller, Even that would be possible. But I just wrote a general method that can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

In one of my apps I use this to set the navbar image for the whole app. Put in on top of your appdelegate file. Works in iOS 4.3 and 5.0.

```
//custom navbar
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavBarLogo.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, -1, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height + 5)];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

http://caydenliew.com/2011/12/customizing-uinavigationbar/

this is how to do it ....